# data binding - ui grid

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to implement UI-grid into my app. Everything works fine when I assign static data to `gridOptions.data`; however, when I assign the data to `gridOptions.data` dynamically after loading the data from the server, I always get an empty string. I tried replicating the dynamic behaviour using `$timeout` function as below, and the result is still the same: empty grid.

//ctrl begins

> This works.

```
 $scope.data = [
             { addedBy :"user", displayName:"Name1" },
             { addedBy :"user2", displayName:"Name2" },
             { addedBy :"user3", displayName:"Name3" }
           ];
```

> This does not; leaving grid empty.

```
 $timeout(function () {
       $scope.data = [
         { addedBy :"user", displayName:"Name1" },
         { addedBy :"user2", displayName:"Name2" },
         { addedBy :"user3", displayName:"Name3" }
       ];
     });
```

The rest of the code remains the same.

```
$scope.columnDefs = [
        {name: 'displayName'},
        {name: 'addedBy'}
      ];

$scope.gridOptions = { 
columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs, 
data: $scope.data 
};
```

//ctrl ends

//html begins

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

//html ends

I am pretty the ui-grid should be capable to update the data when data variable changes; so is there something basic that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data isn't available when the grid is initialized. You have to manually call `notifydataChange` for the grid to update or reassign it like Ronald says.

They have an example in their [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/112_swapping_data) of the latter

Comment: thanks @ndoes , any idea what should be the parameter of the notifyDataChange call? Any link to it's examples/documentations would be helpful. I can see the example of removing/adding column in the link you shared, but any specific definition of the notifyDataChange api?

Comment: Ignore; I found it here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/441613f/src/js/core/factories/Grid.js#L617 and here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:Grid

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can do is default the grid definition to an empty array and in the response of your server call assign it to the grid.

```
$scope.columnDefs = [
        {name: 'displayName'},
        {name: 'addedBy'}
      ];

$scope.gridOptions = { 
columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs, 
data: []
}; 

 $timeout(function () {
       $scope.data = [
         { addedBy :"user", displayName:"Name1" },
         { addedBy :"user2", displayName:"Name2" },
         { addedBy :"user3", displayName:"Name3" }
       ];
 $scope.gridOptions.data=$scope.data;
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have very dynamic grid, where data refreshes for lot of parameters. I always assign the data back to $scope.gridOptions.data directly.

I.e

```
$timeout(function () {
   $scope.gridOptions.data = [
     { addedBy :"user", displayName:"Name1" },
     { addedBy :"user2", displayName:"Name2" },
     { addedBy :"user3", displayName:"Name3" }
   ];
 });
```

Data is being reassigned here, for your every search result

NotifyDataChange event can be used like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
     //set gridApi on scope
     $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
   };
```

You have to add uiGridConstants dependency in your controller.
But from my findings/tests, if you reassign the data to gridOptions.data, then notifyDataChange event is not required.

Comment: does this work for you? It's strange coz as per the documentation, I found that one needs to call 'notifyDataChange' event, without which, the data is not supposed to be updated on the grid.

Comment: I found that I am using notifyDataChange event as well on grid. But in this scenario, data is being reassigned, so I think it should work without that event. I will be testing it sometime today, and update you with my results.

Comment: Yes tested it, reassigning of data doesn't need notifyDataChange event